# fatal: cannot update the ref 'HEAD': unable to append to '.git/logs/HEAD': Permission denied

Tags: php, git, github, cakephp

I have been trying to commit to my local git repository but i always receive the above error. I checked online and all solutions are for linux machines(ie they involve using 'sudo') but I am running windows 7. How can i fix the error? thanks in advance :)

```
fatal: cannot update the ref 'HEAD': unable to append to '.git/logs/HEAD': Permission denied
```

Comment: Figure out why you've denied yourself permission to write to your own files?

Comment: @torek I tried checking my folders for permissions and I do have write permissions. I don't understand the reasons for the error.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try a simple reboot, followed by your Git command right after login.

That way, I would minimize the possibility of another process keeping a handle to `.git/logs/HEAD`, preventing Git to access/update that file.

Comment: What version of git are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.29.2.

Comment: In that case, it must be a right issue of some kind. Would the issue persists if you clone the repository elsewhere?

Comment: when Use the command 'git --version', i get the output 'git version 2.29.2.windwos.2'

Comment: let me try that